# How to allow to drag drop to sort items only when using a mouse?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm trying to implement the drag-drop sort feature into my app and I'm having a little problem.
Let's say I have something like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Source, Mode=OneWay}"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          CanReorderItems="True"
          CanDragItems="True"
          AllowDrop="True"
          DragItemsStarting="MyList_DragItemsStarting"
          DragItemsCompleted="MyList_OnDragItemsCompleted"/>
```

I'm handling all the stuff I need from the DragItemsStarting and Completed events, and it all works fine.

The problem though is that I have some other code that is triggered when the user is using a touch screen (like swipe actions and stuff) and I want the drag/drop operation to *only be available* when using a mouse.

I'm not seeing a place where I can switch depending on the pointer device type, and I don't know where should I look.

Is there a way to do that? Has anyone implemented something like this and can explain how to code that?

Thank you for your help!

Sergio

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UIViewSettings class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uiviewsettings.aspx) to get the current interaction mode, and enable or disable your wanted function for example like this:

```
switch (UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode)
{
    case UserInteractionMode.Mouse:
        listView.AllowDrop = true;
        listView.CanDragItems = true;
        listView.CanReorderItems = true;
        break;

    case UserInteractionMode.Touch:
    default:
        listView.AllowDrop = false;
        listView.CanDragItems = false;
        listView.CanReorderItems = false;
        break;
}
```

"listView" is the name of `ListView` which is defined in XAML code. You can use this code for example whenever the Point is over the `ListView`, or the Page is loaded or other time.

Comment: This looks great! But, what if the app is running on a device with both a mouse and a touch screen? I want the items to be sorted only when the user tries to drag them using the mouse, is there a way to implement that? Thanks!

Comment: @Sergio0694, Didn't test it, I don't have a device now, only emulator, by emulator we can select the input mode, but can you try to put this code at the beginning inside the `DragItemsStarting` event? Look forward to your testing.

Comment: Seems to be working fine right now - it works on my PC using a mouse, and it reports the use of a touch screen (so that I can cancel the drag operation) when I tested it on my phone. I'm still not sure how this will work when using an hybrid device though

Answer (score 0):

So there are many solutions for this. But why always reinvent the wheel. There is a cool library which you can use for your stuff.

So the [GongSolutions.WPF.DragDrop](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop) library is a drag'n'drop framework for WPF and you can use it for ListView, ListBox or whatever ItemsControls.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}"
  dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
  dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
  dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}" />
```

It's MVVM ready and a sample demo is also there where you can see the library in action.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working on a UWP app, and not on WPF. Do some of the other solutions you were talking about work for UWP/WinRT as well? Thanks!